# Where does weight factors come into play with real data (in R)?

Tags: r, weights, survey-weights

I do understand the IMHO simple concept using weights to fit a sample to another (real) population. Calculating the weight factors is not hard. Regarding to my MWE there maybe is a more elegant R way but it works in my case.

But what I don't get is to how to apply the calculated weight factors to my real data.

In the example below there are 50 people in the sample: 36% female and 64% male.
The "real" population is 60% female and 40% male. So weight factors I calculated are

```
  female     male 
1.666667 0.625000
```

In this MWE I have to types of result variables. The `foo` is a categorical variable with `TRUE` and `FALSE`. How to apply the weight factors on this? Imagine a survey question the people can answer with "Yes" or "No".

The second more complicated (for me) is kind of a likert scale from 0 to 4. How do I weight there? Imagine this as a survey question like "How do you feel on that scale from 0 (absolute bad) to 4 (awesome)?".

```
set.seed(0)

k = 50
df <- data.frame(
    gender = sample(c("female", "male", "male"), k, replace = TRUE),
    foo = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), k, replace = TRUE),
    bar = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), k, replace = TRUE)
)

# Frequency
# tab = xtabs(~ gender + foo, data=df)
tab = table(df$gender)
print(tab)

# Fraction
frac = addmargins(prop.table(tab))
print(frac)

# Real poluatin gender fraction
real_female_frac = 0.6
real_male_frac = 0.4

# Weights
weight_female = real_female_frac / frac["female"]
weight_male = real_male_frac / frac["male"]
print(c(weight_female, weight_male))

print(table(df$foo))
print(table(df$bar))
```

## Example with `foo`

```
> table(df$gender, df$foo)
        
         FALSE TRUE
  female     9    8
  male      20   13
```

This is the frequency in the sample. Now do I have to mulitplicate the `female` row with `1.666667` and the `male` with `0.625`?

```
> t["female",] * weight_female
   FALSE     TRUE 
15.88235 14.11765 

> t["male",] * weight_male
    FALSE      TRUE 
12.121212  7.878788
```

## Example with `bar`

```
> addmargins(table(df$gender, df$bar), 1)
       
          0  1  2  3  4
  female  3  5  6  1  3
  male    7  6  8  7  4
  Sum    10 11 14  8  7
```